# How can I distribute $9$ people in $3$ groups of $3$ people?

Tags: combinatorics

How can I distribute $9$ people in $3$ groups of $3$ people? The order of the groups and the order of the people doesn't matter.

I would like to know the procedure to solve it. The solution is $280$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the $9$ people, the $3$ members of the first group can be chosen in ${9\choose 3}$ ways.

From the remaining $6$ people, the $3$ members of the second group can be chosen in ${6\choose 3}$ ways.

From the remaining $3$ people, the $3$ members of the third group can be chosen in ${3\choose 3}$ ways.

According to the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) we get:
$${9\choose 3}{6\choose 3}{3\choose 3}=1680$$
However, the product rule considers the disjoint sets. In other words, this result shows the number of ways to create $3$ groups of $3$ people in the following scenrio: there are $3$ rooms with $9$, $6$ and $3$ people, respectively, and $3$ from each room are selected.

In your problem, the sets are not disjoint. In other words, the following $3!$ selections are considered as one selection:
$$(173)(256)(489) =(173)(489)(256)=(256)(173)(489)=\\
(256)(489)(173)=(489)(173)(256)=(489)(256)(173)$$
Hence, you must divide the above result by $3!$ (the number of groups) to get $280$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{{ 9 \choose 3} {6 \choose 3} { 3 \choose 3}}{ 3!}$$

First you’re choosing 3 people from 9 for the first group. Then you’re choosing 3 people from the 6 remaining for the second group. Lastly, you could say that you’re choosing 3 people from the 3 remaining for the third group, but of course there’s only one way to do that, so you could ignore that factor.

The $3!$ in the denominator is because the order of the groups doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 0):

Pick $\binom{9}{3}$ people for group 1, then $\binom{6}{3}$ for group 2 and the remaining are group 3. Then note that the order of the groups is irrelevant so we divide by $3! = 6$ for compensating the overcounting.

And $\binom{9}{3} \binom{6}{3} \frac{1}{3!} = \frac{9!}{3!6!} \frac{6!}{3!3!} \frac{1}{3!} = \frac{9!}{6^4} = 280$